# Using a camera and getting a big block of errors I don't understand

Tags: python, camera, picamera

So far I've just been following tutorials to set up the camera to do more complex things later, but I always get this block of errors (below). I've tried googling the errors and haven't found anything that matches.

The code I'm running

```
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
import time

picam = Picamera2()

config = picam.create_preview_configuration()
picam.configure(config)

picam.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)

picam.start()
time.sleep(2)
picam.capture_file("test.jpg")

picam.close()
```

The errors

```
[0:02:05.340512109] [2425]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.1.0+118-563cd78e
[0:02:05.379671331] [2433]  WARN RPiSdn sdn.cpp:39 Using legacy SDN tuning - please consider moving SDN inside rpi.denoise
[0:02:05.383774054] [2433]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:444 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx708@1a to Unicam device /dev/media1 and ISP device /dev/media2
[0:02:05.383849831] [2433]  INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1142 Using configuration file '/usr/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
[0:02:05.387437054] [2425]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.1.0+118-563cd78e
[0:02:05.425886813] [2436]  WARN RPiSdn sdn.cpp:39 Using legacy SDN tuning - please consider moving SDN inside rpi.denoise
[0:02:05.428834165] [2436]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:444 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx708@1a to Unicam device /dev/media1 and ISP device /dev/media2
[0:02:05.428912498] [2436]  INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1142 Using configuration file '/usr/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
[0:02:05.440365942] [2425]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1183 configuring streams: (0) 640x480-XBGR8888 (1) 1536x864-SBGGR10_CSI2P
[0:02:05.441044109] [2436]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:608 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx708@1a - Selected sensor format: 1536x864-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1536x864-pBAA
```

If it's relevant I'm using a Pi 4, and the camera module 3

Comment: For the record, it seems to still be opening the preview and taking a still, but I'm just trying to figure out what its trying to tell me and how/if I need to fix it.

Comment: I can't see any errors.

Comment: These are the types of messages developers like to put in their code to tell them how the internal work is going.  The INFO messages are just stating facts, like the version of libcamera being used or the paths used to access the camera.  WARN message mean "you should know about this, but it is probably not a problem.  But you should learn about it so you can decide if you want to ignore it or make changes to eliminate it."  I guess the messages are issued on .start_preview() and again on start().  That is why they repeat.  Disclaimer:  I don't have a camera, so I'm guessing, but maybe helps.

Comment: WRT "legacy SDN tuning" warning, look at "Raspberry Pi Camera Algorithm and Tuning Guide".  Section 5.6 describes SDN, including "The SDN (Spatial Denoise) control algorithm generates parameters for controlling the ISP’s spatial denoise function."  I have no clue what it is talking about, but reading the Tuning Guide and searching for "spatial denoise" will probably be better than searching for "sdn".